# Can I redefine output formatter for one controller method in Net Core 6?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-core-6.0, output-formatting

All my method in Backend API working fine and return correct JSON by the same way

```
Return OK(obj)
Return Unauthorized()
Return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, obj)
```

But in one method I want return raw JSON without standard formatter. I have correct JArray as result of method, for example lake this

[image: correct JSON]

However, when I try to return this JSON as result of controller I receive this result

[image: wrong result]

Any experiments like transform my JArray to object and return IActionResult with object was failed because JArray can be different and has complex and sophisticated structure. Therefore I want to redefine output formatter for this method. But don't understand how it's possible for exactly one method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JArray is the class in `Newtonsoft.Json`. As part of the work to improve the ASP.NET Core shared framework, `Newtonsoft.Json` has been removed from the ASP.NET Core shared framework for .NET 6.

You need add the `Newtonsoft.Json` support according to your requirement.

Follow the steps:

1.Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package.

2.Update Program.cs to call `AddNewtonsoftJson`.

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```